# codeigniter session is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, pagination

I'm using codeigniter
i want to show some data taken form a database by querying as following.

```
$this->db->where('sex !=', $iam);
  $this->db->where('sex', $searching_for);
  $this->db->where('Age >=' , $age_from);
  $this->db->where('Age <=' , $age_to);
 if($Province != 1){
     $this->db->where('Province' , $Province);
 }

        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get("members");
        return $query->result_array();
```

The `$iam,$searching_for, $age, $age_to` is provided by user and I'm passing them from conttroller file using session array.

```
    $search_info=array(
    'iam'           =>  $this->input->post('iam'),
    'searching_for' =>  $this->input->post('searching_for'),
    'age_from'      =>  $this->input->post('age_from'),
    'age_to'        =>  $this->input->post('age_to'),
    'country'       =>  $this->input->post('country'),
    'Province'      =>  $this->input->post('Province')
);

$this->session->set_userdata(array("search_info" => $search_info));
```

and my pagination function is also in controller file and it is like this

```
public function pagination(){
        $this->load->library("pagination");
        $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "controller_search/index";

    $this->load->model('models_search');
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->models_search->search();

    $config["per_page"] = 1;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    //$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;3
    //echo $this->uri->segment(3);
    //echo ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;3;
    $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data["search_result"] = $this->models_search->fetch_categories($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['error'] = '';
    $this->load->view('home_header.php');
    $this->load->view('search/search_result',$data);
}
```

But the thing is when i click the page numbers it didn't show any thing, i tried commenting all the where clues in the query and then it works.
So i think the error is in session array and i tried to `var_dump` the session_all so then it shows `array(0){}`

Can anyone help me in this case ?

Comment: what does `var_dump( $this->session->all_userdata())` output? Is it blank?

Comment: firstime it is showing this
 array(6) { ["iam"]=> string(1) "m" ["searching_for"]=> string(1) "w" ["age_from"]=> string(2) "20" ["age_to"]=> string(2) "37" ["country"]=> string(2) "lk" ["Province"]=> string(1) "1" } }

but wehn i click on a page , then it is showing false
 array(6) { ["iam"]=> bool(false) ["searching_for"]=> bool(false) ["age_from"]=> bool(false) ["age_to"]=> bool(false) ["country"]=> bool(false) ["Province"]=> bool(false) } }

Comment: The session is getting set for the first time but when navigated to some other page or same page, the session is getting destroyed. right?

Comment: In your controller have you included `$this->load->library('session');`, unless you are autoloading sessions.

Comment: yep that's it sir :(
actually i'm auto loading it sir. i use another session array for loging in to the system. and it is working fine

Comment: Below `$this->session->set_userdata(array("search_info" => $search_info));` add `$this->session->set_userdata('dummy', 'somevalue');` and check whether `dummy` session exists throughout.

Comment: yes it shows in every page.

Comment: So its evident that there's no problem setting sessions in your controller. You are setting the session values obtained through `POST`. Therefore first time when it contain details, session variables are set with those details but second time with no details in post variables, the session variables are overwritten with empty values.

Comment: i did so. but the result is same sir.

Comment: Please check my last comment. The problem is that the session variables are getting overwritten even if null values are passed. You have to do a check to find out whether the post variables are empty or not and set the session variables accordingly.

Comment: i took all the post values to variables and then i set those variables to the session array. but still the same thing is happening

Comment: ok. Now close every thing and start from first(close and reopen browser or do a sess_destroy). For the first time enter the values in the text fields and press submit or whatever is provided ie the form should be submitted with values. Now session is set and it will display values. Now immediately replace `$this->session->set_userdata(array("search_info" => $search_info));` with `//$this->session->set_userdata(array("search_info" => $search_info));`  and save the file. Now try clicking some other link(may be pagination) and check if the session exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$this->session->set_userdata("search_info" => $search_info);
```

code to set session

Answer (score 1):

I think you are accessing session array wrong way.

Instead of

```
$iam
```

use

```
$this->session->userdata('iam');
```

Or

```
$this->session->userdata('$iam');
```

Whichever works in your case....

Answer (score 1):

Set your session data by this code:

```
$this->session->set_userdata("sess_data", "mydata");
```

Retrive this session data by this code:

```
$this->session->userdata("sess_data");
```

Comment: "Your", not "ur". Chat speak is specifically disallowed here.

Answer (score 0):

I just took all the posted values to variables in index function and then i put them in to session array as

```
 $search_info=array(
            'iam'           =>  $iam,
            'searching_for' =>  $searching_for,
            'age_from'      =>  $age_from,
            'age_to'        =>  $age_to,
            'country'       =>  $country,
            'Province'      =>  $Province
        );

       $this->session->set_userdata(array("search_info" => $search_info));
```

then i redirect it to pagination function. then it works neatly. before it was overwrite the post items and the session array when i moving towards pages. now because of the redirect it was stoped. as i think. any way it is working now very well
than you every one for helping me. 
specially Mr.John Blake thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have load the session library.If not either load in your controller as

```
$this->load->library('session')
```

or you may auto load session in library of config/autoload.php